# undefined function when accessed from asynchronous function

Tags: javascript

I don't understand, why when I set a function to an object instance, whenever it is accessed from something asynchronous, like setTimeout or a promise, it is undefined. Can someone please explain? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

```
function Animal() {
    this.check = function () {
        writeln(typeof this.test);
    }
    setTimeout(this.check, 1000); // returns undefined
}

var animal = new Animal();
animal.test = function () {

}
animal.check(); // returns function
```

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `function A() { this.x = 42; this.foo = function () { console.log(this.x); }; } var obj = new A(); var f = obj.foo; f();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're losing context here:

```
setTimeout(this.check, 1000);
```

So therefore `this` inside `check` will be `window`, which does not have a `test` property. Maybe do:

```
setTimeout(this.check.bind(this), 1000);
```

*Side note: Having dynamically assigned functions is a performance killer and therefore bad style. There's always a better way...*

Comment: @melpoleme thanks, sorry for overriding your changes ;/

Comment: thanks I get it now. I am using nativescript and I had trouble firing an event from self made objects. I need to trigger an ui update when certain things happen I thought this as an workaround.

Comment: @jacklin its hard to give a spefific advise based on the little code we have...

Comment: I have an object like Animal that talks to sqlite via functions that return promises. I'd like to fire an event or call a function like this from inside the resolve promise which would trigger a function in another file, which handles ui, so it could reload.

Comment: @jacklin then your solution is acceptable, however i would rather prefer an EventListener pattern, like: `animal.on("update", function(){...});`